# new Date('yyyy-mm-dd') sets timezone to local timezone but new Date('yyyyy-mm-dd') sets timezone to GMT

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

new Date('yyyy-mm-dd') sets timezone to local timezone but
new Date('yyyyy-mm-dd') sets timezone to GMT

```
new Date("2019-05-29")
Wed May 29 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

new Date("11111-05-29")
Mon May 29 11111 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Why does this behavior occur

Comment: See [Differences in assumed time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first one is creating a UTC date but you're displaying it in your local timezone. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)...

> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local

Your second date is being created in your local timezone. The reason for this is because the [ISO 8601 standard only supports a 4-digit year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) (by default), therefore it does not qualify for the above condition.